# How to use python3.12 as the default version in macos?

Tags: macos, homebrew, python, sonoma

I recently updated to python3.12 because I needed the newest version for ProperTree to work correctly.
I installed python3.12 with `brew install python@3.12` and then ran `which python3`, which outputs `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python`. So now, my question is: How do I change the default python3 command to the newest installed python via brew? I created an alias in my ~/.zshrc, but that doesn't solve the issue directly.

Does someone know the solution? I'm on Apple Silicon running Sonoma 14.1, btw.
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I use the python installer directly from python.org, and have never had a problem of this sort.

Comment: When you install python@3.12 it tells you how: Add `/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/libexec/bin` to your path. If that's not working for ProperTree then it's an issue with ProperTree. Apps must either respect your zshrc or must allow you to manually select your python version